# best performance method to LOOP through MYSQL table

Tags: mysql

I am looking to iterate through a USERS table, and for each user selected based on my where clauses, perform a bunch of mysql queries within the LOOP, including temp table creates, using prepare statements, etc

What is the best way in terms of performance should this be done. Using while, for each, for, repeat ?

eg.(Pseudo code)

```
foreach user_name in (select user_name from users where user_type = 'SP' and active = 'Y')
do
    set @l_query1 = concat("create temp_table_t1 select * from ...")
    PREPARE ..
    EXECUTE ...

    set @l_query2 = ... 
    ....
    .... etc .. 
done
```

Ok, i have a table users, where pK = user_name.

So,this query will be fast to execute,
I just need to LOOP through this resultSet, and execute the remaining of the mySQL queries within the LOOP. 
How can i LOOP through the resultSet of a simple select ?

thanks

Comment: What you are describing is a RBAR action on a dataset. This is going to be slow probably no matter what you use. IF you could show us the data structures and queries we might be able to solve it in a SETS based way.

Comment: you can do all this stuff in one query with joins which will of course takes less execution time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no difference in performance between *while*, *for-each*, *repeat*, etc.

If you're looking for performance gains, consider where you might reduce the number of queries the code executes on the database.  For example, it would be a huge help to run a query once for all users, rather than running it *once each for every user*.